# How to interrupt another thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am reading the book of *CPP-Concurrency-In-Action-2ed-2019*. In **chapter 9.2.1**, the author gives a simple example to show how to implement a basic interruptible_thread:

```
class interrupt_flag
{
public:
  void set();
  bool is_set() const;
};
thread_local interrupt_flag this_thread_interrupt_flag;  // 1

class interruptible_thread
{
  std::thread internal_thread;
  interrupt_flag* flag;
public:
  template<typename FunctionType>
  interruptible_thread(FunctionType f)
  {
    std::promise<interrupt_flag*> p;  // 2
    internal_thread=std::thread([f,&p]{  // 3
      p.set_value(&this_thread_interrupt_flag);
      f();  // 4
    });
    flag=p.get_future().get();  // 5
  }
  void interrupt()
  {
    if(flag)
    {
      flag->set();  // 6
    }
  }
};
```

But about it, I have several wonders.

1. If `p.set_value` in the new thread runs after the constructor of `interruptible_thread`, then doesn't std::promise `p` becomes a dangling reference because `p` is just a local variable in constructor?
2. What is the purpose to use std::promise `p`?Would that be the same only using `flag=&this_thread_interrupt_flag` by passing `flag` in?
3. When I call `interrupt()`, how could it interrupt the new thread, I don't see any triggers?

Comment: Consider using `volatile` and perhaps `attribute((weak))` on Linux computers with [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler

Comment: Note that [jthread](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/jthread/request_stop) is now available and packages this feature up nicely.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch `volatile` has very few uses in modern c++, i don't see how it's relevant here?

Comment: @AlanBirtles: I understood that f1msch is asking about hardware [interrupts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt). Then `volatile` could be relevant. Probably `p` needs to be some smart pointer....? Or some `atomic` one?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I see no reference to hardware interrupts in the question. `p` works perfectly as it is and doesn't need to be modified

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the 1) promise object will not get out of scope, because after the thread is started you call

```
flag=p.get_future().get();
```

and [future::get](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/get) is blocking until the result is ready. Then
this might already answer your second question: promise and future are used to ensure that constructor blocks until particular line in thread is executed.

For the 3) I don't know yet, I think it depends on the particular implementation of `interrupt_flag` and probably implies some requirements on callable object passed to the thread.

== EDIT ==

Q 3) Yes, just keep reading, some basic example with exception being thrown is already explained in chapter 9.2.2; Then you will get some more advanced snippets.